# huge zend framework project and where to place models

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, structure, models

We have a huge Zend Framework project, it's basically a website in 4 different languages and with a fair amount of pages. Usually my application handle 10~15 database tables and probably 5/6 controllers so I place all my model under `applications/models`.

The problem with that project doing the same would make copy the same models in each modules and probably make a lot of duplicate code and make the maintenance being difficult. I am wondering if it would wise to puts the models under `library`?

How do you people are doing in such case? some solutions, I am thinking of in my order of preference

- put models and shared code under `/library`
- make a common module and play with the auto loading to load this classes from any modules
- dirty but possible setup some symbolic links so the files in models come all from the same source ... but probably bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I keep all library code, including models, under /library. IMO, that's what it's there for. Then, if you need to share libraries (incl. models) between apps, you can do so with a single symlink or git submodule:

Your local app:

```
/myapp/application/
/myapp/public/
/myapp/library/
/myapp/library/MyApp/
```

Pulling in external dependencies:

```
/myapp/library/OtherLib (git submodule of a separate repo)
/myapp/library/ExtraLib (symlink to /path/to/ExtraLib/)
```

Or:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . ':/path/to/ExtraLib')
```

If you separate models from the library, you'd have two mount points for every dependency.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I typically structure my application, although I have stored them in the `library` folder in other projects. I prefer this structure over storing them in the library as Models are application specific, whereas my library is used to store application-less(?) classes (typical Auth, Filters etc)

```
/application
    /models
        // Models
    /modules
        /default
            /controllers
                // Default Controllers
        /admin
            /controllers
                // Admin Controllers
/library
    // Library Classes
```